# MySQL from Hibernate syntax error

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I use `Hibernate` to get data from `MySQL 5.5.28` database, this is query from Hibernate with `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` error:

```
Hibernate: 
select user0_.uid as uid1_0_0_, user0_.motorcycle as motorcyc2_0_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_0_, user0_.username as username4_0_0_
from db-jade-na-zlot.users user0_ 
where user0_.uid=1;
```

i try to check this in phpMyAdmin and this query works fine:

```
select user0_.uid as uid1_0_0_, user0_.motorcycle as motorcyc2_0_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_0_, user0_.username as username4_0_0_
from users user0_ 
where user0_.uid=1;
```

i checked 5 times database name in hibernate.cfg.xml, but it's ok. What i'm doing wrong?

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db-jade-na-zlot</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">vertrigo</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="pl.jadenazlot.model.User"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

error:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-jade-na-zlot.users user0_ where user0_.uid=1' at line 1
```

Comment: can you post the entire stacktrace, also are you specifying a specific HibernateDialect, and is that dialect up to date?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-jade-na-zlot.users user0_ where user0_.uid=1' at line 1

Comment: can you update your answer and include your hibernate config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `db-jade-na-zlot` a valid schema/database name?
Probably you need to thick it putting

> ``

around this name to teach Hibernate to treat as identifier and quoting it into generated SQL

Comment: my-db was temporary name for post, correct is db-jade-na-zlot.

Comment: i tried in phpMyAdmin query with " FROM 'db-jade-na-zlot'.'users' ... ", but still is syntax error.

Comment: backthick is the rdbms independant identifier quote char for hibernate; for MySQL (looking at dialect) the quote character is the backthick itself (but this is just a coincidence)

Comment: helps change db-jade-na-zlot to dbjadenazlot, thanks